# Logical equivalence proof of $\forall x[\forall y(P(x,y))] \equiv \forall y[\forall x(P(x,y))]$

Tags: logic, computer-science, first-order-logic

So I have been asked to *prove* the following logical equivalence:

> $\forall x[\forall y(P(x,y))] \equiv \forall y[\forall x(P(x,y))]$

Of course, I understand intuitively that the equivalence is true but I'm having a hard time to actually prove it. Should it be done through other equivalences? If so, through which ones? Or maybe I should explain in my own words since it so obvious?

Comment: Yes you can prove it. But what are the logical equivalences regarding quantifiers that you know ?

Answer (score 0):

Assume $$\forall x[\forall y(P(x,y))]$$
By specialization of $x$
$$\forall y(P(x,y)) $$
and by sepcialization of $y$
$$ P(x,y).$$
Now generalize over $x$
$$\forall x(P(x,y)) $$
and generalize over $y$:
$$\forall y[\forall x(P(x,y))]$$